# Is there a human version of event data recorder?

Tags: technology

For avoidance of false accusation, this would be a nice tool. Even if there will be some extra privacy issues which were not applied to drive recorder but applied to the human version of it, I think one can overcome them with some modifications.

**EDIT**

By "human version" I mean that a human can wear a tiny recorder 24 hours a day, whether he's in a car or not. I'm not sure whether this sort of product was commercialized yet, although some people proposed that police should wear it during his duty, so that police shooting to innocent citizens will not happen. If the access to the recorder is possible only when it is needed in the court, I suppose this will clear privacy issues.

Comment: What is a "drive recorder" and what do you mean by a human version of it? Do you mean something you use while driving a vehicle? Like a personal video recorder you turn on when pulled over by the police? or something more like a "black box" that records where and what you were doing in the event of an accident?

Comment: Sorry, the terminology I used was uncommon. I mean the black box that records exactly as you described.

Comment: I've given an answer but I don't think it comes under the category of 'life hack', it would be better suited as a software request.

Comment: I was not sure which site of stack exchange to post my question. So, I appreciate your suggestion and answer. Since I don't have enough reputation to migrate this thread to another site, I flagged my question, stating that it should be migrated to Software Recommendations, so that it will be done by the moderator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"AutoGuard Dash Cam - Blackbox" Sounds perfect for you, if i am understanding you correctly, you are using a lot of terminology i don't really get, but it isn't really a life hack.

> Your smart phone can be clever as you with AutoGuard, the best
>   Blackbox application, will give you wonderful experiences. Key
>   Features
>
> - (Pro) Background recording: Multitasking with other apps (like    navigation)
> - Upload videos on YouTube.com with captions for location and time       information
> - Capture photos at important situation automatically
> - Show the video and map information on one screen
> - Automatically starts video recording when put into car dock or       connect with bluetooth devices
> - Records driving video, speed, GPS, and nearest address
> - Supports high resolutions (1080p, 720p)
> - Traces path driven on 3D Google maps
> - Snapshot (supports auto focus, flash & gallery)
> - Send recorded information via E-mail

[Link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hovans.autoguard&hl=en_GB)

Comment: This application sounds awesome. But by "human version" I mean that a human can wear a tiny recorder 24 hours a day, whether he's in a car or not. I'm not sure whether this sort of product was commercialized yet, although some people proposed that police should wear it during his duty, so that police shooting to innocent citizens will not happen.

Comment: I don't see why this wouldn't work on your person. Are you wanting to purchase a device, or just use an app? If it is a device this is definately the wrong area to ask. Might be worth looking at this: http://www.amazon.com/720p-Mini-Metal-Camera-Police/dp/B009Z0QFO6 
We wear them in the police force to allow evidence gathering throughout a shift.

Comment: Oh you're totally right! I was not aware of it.